# Ship deadweight should be deadmass?

Tags: mass, mass-energy, weight

The question is about ship stability calculations. We need to solve moment = force × distance, but in stability they put mass × distance. How, and why? Deadweight is the total weight of cargo, stores, etc. which a ship carries or can carry. -"this will produce a maximum dead weight of 72,350 tons".
If it is in tonnes how can it be weight? It should be mass. If the cargo of 200 kg is loaded 2 meters from center line it will create momentum of ? Moment = 200 × 2 = 400 kg m, or 0,4 tm.

How can we put mass in equation for moment, is should be force, and force is in Newtons. Weight is force, mass is not. In water ship has weight or mass? Why do they use word weight in stability when the measure is in kg or tonnes. It should be mass?!

I know that in physics mass and weight are two different things. Mass is not a force, weight is force, but ship in water has force, but we express it in tonnes, not newtons. Is it because mass × gravity = volume × density × gravity so if we remove gravity we get mass = volume  × density, so if the ship, water it floats in and cargo that is going to be loaded are in the same gravity force field we can use amount of mass as weight?

Comment: I understand the difference between weight and mass, what I need is why do we use tonnes (mass) for ship buoyancy force in water (weight). Is it because everything is in the same gravity field and: force = mass×gravity = volume×density×gravity so if we remove gravity since it is the same, force = mass = volume×density ?

Comment: This is not duplicate question since I am not asking difference between weight and mass. i know that they are different. I am asking why in ship stability calculations we can use mass as force (weight), how is that mathematically correct, is it because gravity in buoyancy force can be canceled out?